# Why does Ubuntu detect two screens when I have only one?

Tags: 12.10, display

which is annoying, because when I take screenshot it takes screenshot from both screens (from an existing one and a non-existing one).

[image]

Comment: It seems that it takes the screenshot of adjacent horizontal workspaces. Can you confirm by placing a different file/folder in the right workspace and again taking the screenshot?